# Ruby until loop ending too soon

Tags: ruby, watir

I'm using Watir to collect all items from a page with an infinite scroll. Created an until loop that counts the number of items in the 'before' state, scrolls to the bottom of the page and counts the new number of items.

It's supposed to run until all items are captured but it stops only after one scroll.

What am I doing wrong?

```
browser.goto 'https://bubble.io/plugins'
old_app_as = ['a']
new_app_as = ['b', 'c']

until old_app_as.count == new_app_as.count
  old_app_as = browser.divs(class: 'rows')[1].as
  browser.scroll.to [0, 999999999]
  sleep(10)
  new_app_as = browser.divs(class: 'rows')[1].as
end
```

Comment: Do you have to yield somehow to let the page load? Not sure if waitr is blocking here.

Comment: Check out [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `ElementCollections` relocates the elements when using `Enumerable` methods. You can see this in the [Watir code](https://github.com/watir/watir/blob/main/lib/watir/element_collection.rb#L21-L36):

```
def each(&blk)
  reset!
  to_a.each(&blk)
end
```

This means that in the `until old_app_as.count == new_app_as.count`:

1. `old_app_as` will re-locate the collection find the currently available links, which it will find 40 (ie with the extra loaded page).
2. `new_app_as` will also re-locate the currently available links, which it will find the same 40.
3. The two values are the same so the loop exits.

You need to store `old_app_as` and `new_app_as` in a way that will not relocate each time. I think the simplest solution is to convert them to an `Array` using `#to_a`:

```
until old_app_as.count == new_app_as.count
  old_app_as = browser.divs(class: 'rows')[1].as.to_a
  browser.scroll.to [0, 999999999]
  sleep(10)
  new_app_as = browser.divs(class: 'rows')[1].as.to_a
end
```